Lightroom: Change default date format
Lightroom UI displays dates in DD/MM/YYYY format in Loupe View Overlay, Metadata panel etc.
Is it possible to change this to another format?

The format of data/time usually is get from the setting of the operating system. What format do you want?

I was after YYYY-MM-DD. And yes - changing the format in the system changes it in Lightroom, albeit only partially. The metadata panel still shows DD/MM/YYYY but at least I have the format I wanted in the Loupe View. Thanks.

The format of data/time usually is get from the setting of the operating system. So you can change the locales and time/date format in your operating system and test.
Do not forget some info is extracted from EXIF information and may or may not be converted to the OS format.
